# Summing nested arrays of different length in python

Tags: arrays, nested, sum

I have the arrays p1 and p2 where they each look like

```
array([  1.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,   8.90000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+00,   3.94090600e-06,   2.22958010e-02,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00])
```

and

```
array([  1.00000000e+00,   4.00000000e+00,   8.90000000e+01,
         1.00000000e+00,   3.94090600e-06,   2.87729900e-03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])
```

So p2 is longer than p1. Note the numbers themselves are unimportant.

They are in the list

```
p = [p1,p2]
```

I would like to sum them such that the extra values in p2 are truncated. I thought I could do

```
sum(p[:][0:10])
```

But this produces an operand error. Actually I'm really unsure if I even understand what the sum function is trying to do in this instance. I know it works in the instance that p1 and p2 are the same length though.

Basically I want the result that

```
p[0][0:10]+p[1][0:10]
```

gives, which is

```
array([  2.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,   1.78000000e+02,
         2.00000000e+00,   7.88181200e-06,   2.51731000e-02,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00])
```

I had come up with a workaround but it's disgusting and I feel like there is probably a way to get the sum function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sum to do that directly. `sum` basically just iterate over a list and total up the elements like

```
def sum(iterables):
  total = 0
  for elem in iterables: total += elem
  return total
```

You can use list comprehension to achieve your goal as below

```
# Find out the minimum length of list inside p to truncate excess elements
truncated_len = min([len(list) for list in p])
# Sum up each elements
result = [sum([p[j][i] for j in range(len(p))]) for i in range(truncated_len)]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this produces the same operand error that just using sum does. I'm just going to stick with my workaround which just copies the arrays line by line into a new data structure. Not exactly elegant but it works.